# Why doesn't the method assign a value to an XML variable?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

In one of the projects, xml reading class loads and parses the content of the file. There are attributes I have to use but when I try to assign these to corresponding variables, it happens nothing, traces empty and latter stages it throws `Error #1010` for an array since it is empty. There is the relevant code below and I miss something for sure.

```
private var xml:XML;
protected function LoadHandler():void
{
    mainXmlLoader.loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,ioErrorListener);
    mainXmlLoader.loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, CompleteXML);
    mainXmlLoader.loader.load(new URLRequest("some-path-of-xml.xml"));
}
protected function CompleteXML(event:Event):void
{
    var titleStr:String;
    var numberStr:String;
    xml = new XML(event.target.data);
    titleStr = xml.@title;
    numberStr = xml.@prodCode;
}
```

---

loaded xml file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<main title="Count of Monte Cristo" version="6.0" prodCode="BNR34" xmlSource="a-Project/files/contents.xml">

</main>
```

---

My question: Although `event.target.data` is not empty/undefined/null and assignable&traceble by `String`, `xml`, `titleStr`, and `numberStr` are all undefined. Why can't I assign any value as type of `XML`?

Comment: Could you post an example of your XML content ?

Comment: @akmozo I added the xml file.

Comment: According to your XML content, your AS3 code looks fine. I don't understand how did you got the `undefined` values ? Did you used some `trace()` inside the `CompleteXML()` method ? ...

Comment: Yes, I had a trace in the method. Flash Builder neglects the trace, watch expression gives error and then I put an if condition to check the xml but nothing happened. My if was like that `if(xml != "")trace("xml is", xml);`

Comment: The PO is not being truthful anyway. He claims that xml, titleStr, and numberStr are undefined but that's just not possible. Those variable are strong typed and their default value can only be null not undefined which happens only for untyped variables.

Comment: @Jamiryo Try to show `xml.toXMLString()` instead of `xml` and without the `if` statement, and to show `titleStr` or `numberStr` inside the same function because they are not accessible outside ...

Comment: @akmozo as you said all three(xml.toXMLString(), titleStr, numberStr) appears as they should be. I guess problem is somewhere else. I thought this line it was because I can't trace.

Comment: @BotMaster Sir/Madam, I might be wrong and uninformed, and please correct me. Does `variable == ""` condition refers to undefined? If not how can I control undefined?

Comment: if you give a type to a variable like in your case: var numberStr:String; that variable can only have two values: null or a String. It cannot be undefined. The only case in AS3 a variable can be undefined is when no type is specified and the compiler as a consequence cannot figure out what type a variable can hold. Ex: var numberStr; (notice no type is given here) in that case numberStr can be undefined.